# Android Listview when long Press a ContextMenu is shown with deleting file option

Tags: android, listview

I have some troubles with my code.
In a listView, when I Long Press a ContextMenu is shown. An option for deleting a file is shown.
But when I press delete in the ContextMenu the app force close.

Any ideas ?
thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                int index, long arg3) {

            registerForContextMenu(listView);  
            return false;
        }
});         

}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Change Name");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        if(item.getTitle()=="Change Name"){function1(item.getActionView(), item.getItemId());}  
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){function2(item.getActionView(), item.getItemId());}  
        else {return false;}  
    return true;  
    }  

    public void function1(View view, int id){  
       //Change Name Code
    }  
    public void function2(View view, int id){  
        String product = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
      File dir = getFilesDir();
      File file = new File(dir, (product));
      boolean deleted = file.delete();

        Toast.makeText(ShowListActivity.this, R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Here is my LogCat

> 10-17 19:10:32.621: E/InputEventReceiver(25683): Exception dispatching
>   input event. 10-17 19:10:32.621: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683): Exception
>   in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 10-17 19:10:32.641:
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683): java.lang.NullPointerException 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   tbj.android.basketballstatistics.ShowListActivity.function2(ShowListActivity.java:92)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   tbj.android.basketballstatistics.ShowListActivity.onContextItemSelected(ShowListActivity.java:79)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2620) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4129)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3657) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3436) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7713) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:746) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3950)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3829)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3521)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5535)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5515)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5486)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5615)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25683):    at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollO 10-17 19:10:32.641:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(25683): Shutting down VM 10-17 19:10:32.641:
>   W/dalvikvm(25683): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x41642db8) 10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683): Process:
>   tbj.android.basketballstatistics, PID: 25683 10-17 19:10:32.641:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25683): java.lang.NullPointerException 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   tbj.android.basketballstatistics.ShowListActivity.function2(ShowListActivity.java:92)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   tbj.android.basketballstatistics.ShowListActivity.onContextItemSelected(ShowListActivity.java:79)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2620) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4129)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3657) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3436) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7713) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2329)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:746) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7893) 10-17
>   19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3950)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3829)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3521)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5535)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5515)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5486)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5615)
>   10-17 19:10:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(25683):  at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInput

Comment: can you show log output so we can have a better idea of the error ?

Comment: @j2emanue my logcat is available now

Comment: There is NullPointerException while executing function2, so use debugging on this function. Are you getting reference of textview? Use OnItemLongClickListener on the listview to get product name.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know what is going wrong here because we don't know what line numbers correspond to the lines of code you have included. But to give you a starting point of how I would solve this problem:

Generally when an Android application crashes, you want to be searching your log for where it says `FATAL EXCEPTION:`. In this case, Android is telling you that the event that broke everything was a NullPointerException at line 92 of the file `ShowListActivity.java`. So you should look there and see what could possibly be wrong with it.

My guess is that what is wrong is you are using `item.getActionView()` incorrectly. I think what you're trying to do is to get the TextView that the user is trying to delete; but `item` does not refer to the "item" the user is trying to delete, but rather the `MenuItem` the user clicked on in order to tell the app to delete that list member.

`getActionView()` also doesn't return anything other than `null` unless you've previously called `setActionView()` on that `MenuItem`; and the only reason you would ever want to do this is if you wanted to set some really complex view to represent that action (an icon or a text field is not complex, as far as what I am talking about.)

The correct way to do what you're trying to accomplish would be to store some sort of identifier for the item the user is going to act on *at the time you create the context menu,* before the user chooses what to do with it; perhaps in a member variable of some sort. Then tell your `function2` method to act using that identifier.

Comment: In general, the way you have implemented this context menu is very unorthodox and is going to result in a lot of extra work for yourself. For example, you should not be defining your menu options in `onCreateContextMenu`, but rather in an external XML file. You should consider reviewing the Android docs on Context Menus: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the position of the long pressed row in a global variable lets say private int pos;
and make pos = index in setOnItemLongClickListener then in function2 get the product name from the array you use to fill the listview using pos

hope that will help